# Python: How to find the near multiple value in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have got a dataframe
**input_df**

```
Item    Space   Size    Max
Apple   0.375   0.375   0.375
Lemon   0.625   0.375   0.75
Melon   0.5     0.375   0.625
```

'*Space*' column value need to be the nearest multiple of '*Size*' column. Also, final `input_df['Space'] <= input_df['Max']`. '*extra*' column to be generated which gives how much space value added/reduced.

**Expected output_df**

```
Item    Space   Size    Max     extra
Apple   0.375   0.375   0.375   0       
Lemon   0.75    0.375   0.75    0.125   #Space value changed to nearest
Melon   0.375   0.375   0.625   -0.125  #Space value changed to nearest
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nearest multiple"? Can you break down the logic?

Comment: Means, Space column value should always be in multiples of Size column value. Like in this case, 0.375, 0.75, 1.125..etc This can be achieved either by adding/reducing space value to it's nearest. If Space value is 0.625, then the nearest Size multiple on considering above/below  is 0.75(not 0.375) and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the nearest multiple using `min` of `floor` and `round` operation on divisible factor of `Space` and `Max` respectively:

```py
pd.DataFrame([np.floor(df["Max"]/df["Size"]), np.round(df["Space"]/df["Size"])]).min() * df["Size"]
```

Full example:

```py
columns = ["Item","Space","Size","Max"]
data = [("Apple",0.375,0.375,0.375),
("Lemon",0.500,0.375,0.75),
("Melon",0.625,0.375,0.75),
("Peach",0.700,0.375,0.625),
("Grape",0.300 ,0.375,0.750)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
# Input
>>     Item  Space   Size    Max
>> 0  Apple  0.375  0.375  0.375
>> 1  Lemon  0.500  0.375  0.750
>> 2  Melon  0.625  0.375  0.750
>> 3  Peach  0.700  0.375  0.625
>> 4  Grape  0.300  0.375  0.750


df["Extra"] = df["Space"]
df["Space"] = pd.DataFrame([np.floor(df["Max"]/df["Size"]), np.round(df["Space"]/df["Size"])]).min() * df["Size"]
df["Extra"] = df["Space"] - df["Extra"]
# Output
>>     Item  Space   Size    Max  Extra
>> 0  Apple  0.375  0.375  0.375  0.000
>> 1  Lemon  0.375  0.375  0.750 -0.125
>> 2  Melon  0.750  0.375  0.750  0.125
>> 3  Peach  0.375  0.375  0.625 -0.325
>> 4  Grape  0.375  0.375  0.750  0.075
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something in the question, this doesn't give the **nearest** multiple. For example on `Grape   0.3     0.375   0.75` this would  change to `0.750` instead of `0.375` (that is the nearest)

Comment: OP can confirm this. "nearest multiple" is very ambiguous term he used here. But good catch. Let me test.

Comment: @user12345 can you confirm the expected output for `Grape   0.3     0.375   0.75`?

Comment: @mozway I think by "nearest" he means nearest to "Max".

Comment: That's a possible interpretation, but then this would mean that the original value of Space is irrelevant to compute the final value. Let's wait and see ;)

Comment: At first, all Space values will be in terms of 1/8th by default in input. So Grape will not hold 0.3 as its value. Second, The Space column need to be converted to its nearest value w.r.t. size value. For eg., if Melon got space 0.625 then its nearest is 0.75 not 0.375. Let me try your version of code as well and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Have tried your code, some logic need to be changed. Usage of Max: When Space is added/reduced, we need to just verify that added/reduced space is within Max. But here, every space is increased until it reaches Max value which should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# get max multiple
MAX = input_df['Max'].div(input_df['Size'])

NEW = (input_df['Space']
       .div(input_df['Size'])        # get multiple
       .clip(upper=MAX.astype(int))  # clip to MAX integer
       .round()                      # round to nearest integer
       .mul(input_df['Size'])        # multiply again by step
      )

# compute the difference to original
input_df['extra'] = NEW.sub(input_df['Space'])
# update original
input_df['Space'] = NEW
```

output:

```
    Item  Space   Size    Max  extra
0  Apple  0.375  0.375  0.375  0.000
1  Lemon  0.750  0.375  0.750  0.125
2  Melon  0.375  0.375  0.625 -0.125
3  Peach  0.375  0.375  0.625 -0.375
4  Grape  0.375  0.375  0.750  0.075
```

used input:

```
    Item  Space   Size    Max
0  Apple  0.375  0.375  0.375
1  Lemon  0.625  0.375  0.750
2  Melon  0.500  0.375  0.625
3  Peach  0.750  0.375  0.625
4  Grape  0.300  0.375  0.750
```

Comment: I added an extra row, let me know if this is correct

Comment: All good but Item Peach alone need not to be reduced because it already got 0.375*2=0.75 multiple value.

Comment: @user12345 but it's above the maximum (maybe this wasn't a possible initial case?)

Comment: Grape is in your input, as of my input all Space values will be within Max value

Comment: OK then it should work as you want ;)

Comment: I'm confused, which one was the correct interpretation of the constraints, mine or that of @Azhar? I'm not talking about the extra dummy examples that I generated but the "closest to Space vs closest to Max" logic.